# Model Validations working properly on local but on not on server

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have implemented client side model validation which is working file on local, 
but on server even if my textbox is empty it shows error but hitting controller respective method.

Comment: It looks like a client (javascript) script bug. How do you implement your "client side model validation"?

Comment: It is model validation in my form as follows       

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}  and at textbox 
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FirstName)

Answer (score 1):

The server is more restrictive about sending errors down ot the client. Try setting the `IncludeErrorDetails` flag on your `httpconfiguation` to verify that this is the underlying issue.

In general though turning this flag on is not the best idea, and you will want to serialize the errors down differently.

For more info: [click here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/youssefm/2012/06/28/error-handling-in-asp-net-webapi/)

Comment: Thanks @Dilshan Perera, but this is normal Internet application not a web api project